# How to fix python not writing to file

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm making a script that reads a dictionary and picks out words that fit a search criteria. The code runs fine, but the problem is that it doesn't write any words to the file "wow" or print them out. The source for the dictionary is https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.zip.

I've tried changing the opening of the file to "w+" instead of "a+" but it didn't make a difference. I checked if there just weren't any words that fitted the criteria but that isn't the issue.

```py
listExample = []  #creates a list

with open("words.txt") as f:  #opens the "words" text file
    for line in f:
        listExample.append(line)

x = 0
file = open("wow.txt","a+") #opens "wow" so I can save the right words to it

while True:
    if x < 5000: # limits the search because I don't want to wait too long
        if len(listExample[x]) == 11: #this loop iterates through all words
            word = listExample[x]     #if the words is 11 letters long  
            lastLetter = word[10]
            print(x)
            if lastLetter == "t":    #and the last letter is t
                file.write(word)      #it writes the word to the file "wow"
                print("This word is cool!",word) #and prints it
            else:
                print(word) #or it just prints it
        x += 1 #iteration
    else:
        file.close()
        break #breaks after 5000 to keep it short
```

It created the "wow" file but it is empty. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You sure the if condition is met to execute `file.write(word)`

Comment: Are you sure all the conditions that lead to writing to the file are met?

Comment: The conditions are that it is a 11 letter word with the letter t at the end. "adolescent" is in the dictionary and is not written to file.

Comment: @ix84gaming, there are _10_ letters in this word, not 11

Comment: `len("adolescent")` gives me 10

Comment: There's a different problem then. Because it shouldn't be printed if it is 10 letters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixes your problem. You were splitting the text in such a way that each word had a line break at the end and maybe a space too. I've put in `.strip()` to get rid of any whitespace. Also I've defined `lastLetter` as `word[-1]` to get the final letter regardless of the word's length.

P.S. Thanks to Ocaso Protal for suggesting strip instead of replace.

```
listExample = []  #creates a list

with open("words.txt") as f:  #opens the "words" text file
    for line in f:
        listExample.append(line)

x = 0
file = open("wow.txt","a+") #opens "wow" so I can save the right words to it

while True:
    if x < 5000: # limits the search because I don't want to wait too long
        word = listExample[x].strip()
        if len(word) == 11:
            lastLetter = word[-1]
            print(x)
            if lastLetter == "t":    #and the last letter is t
                file.write(word + '\n')      #it writes the word to the file "wow"
                print("This word is cool!",word) #and prints it
            else:
                print(word) #or it just prints it
        x += 1 #iteration
    else:
        print('closing')
        file.close()
        break #breaks after 5000 to keep it short
```

Comment: And one more thing ;) The first loop over words.txt can be simplified by using either `list` or `readlines`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects